# Set a non-null, but non-displayed django form field before form.save()

Tags: django, django-forms

Am using django forms on my app. I have a model `Client` like this:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'client'
```

Then I have some other models 'Asset`,`AssetType` and then also specify a form for allowing a client to define their own assets - the asset types are created by the admin.

```
class AssetType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'assettype'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'asset'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class AssetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
```

Now, my problem is that when the Client is logged in, and the want to create a new `Asset`, the `AssetForm`, which I render like this, in the `asset.html`:

```
<FORM id="newasset_form" method="POST" action="/assets/">
      {% csrf_token %}
    <TABLE cellpadding="3" border="0" cellspacing="5">
        <tr><th colspan="2">define a new asset</th></tr>
        {{ form }}
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="create asset" /></td>
    </TABLE>
  </FORM>
```

On the resultant form displayed to the Client, this setup displays the `client` field of the new `Asset` as a `select` with a drop-down of all existing clients, something I want to avoid. I want that client field to be auto-linked to the client whose session created the form - the currently logged in client, and not allow them to set the `client` to any other client. so how do i do this?

I had tried doing this, after the `AssetForm` is posted, to assign this client to the form's client field, then save, but it doesnt work!

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        asset_form = AssetForm(request.POST)
        if asset_form.is_valid():
            asset_form.client = client
            asset_form.save()
```

I want to define my form as :

```
class AssetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        exclude = ('client')
```

so that a client, can't tamper with the `client` field at all, when creating the new Asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AssetForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        exclude = ('client',) # don't forget that comma
```

Use the commit argument of the save method ([**`docs`**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)):

```
if asset_form.is_valid():
    instance = asset_form.save(commit=False)
    instance.client = client
    instance.save()
```

or create an instance of Asset where client is set and use that for the instance argument of creating your form:

```
def someview(request):
    client = Client.objects.get(pk=<some_pk>)
    asset = Asset(client=client)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssetForm(request.POST, instance=asset)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        form = AssetForm(instance=asset)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render_to_response('some_template.html', context,
            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks @DTing, i used the first approach -- simpler for my case, since i don’t want to even client info to client. But setting the `hidden` attribute in the `AssetForm` refused to hide the client field on the form, till i used instead the `fields` attribute to spec what should be displayed. Thanks, the solution worked for me.

Comment: sorry hidden was the wrong word. that should have been `exclude`